# XSLT fails when prefix for name space

Tags: xml, xslt

For transform XML file with a name spaace, I've to to use this name space in XSL file. 
But it doesn't work.

Here is my XML file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data xmlns="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization">
    <parent>
        <string xmlns="">AAA</string>
    </parent>
    <nb>
        <string >2</string>
    </nb>
    <child1>aaa-1
        <s1><string >1aaa-1 </string></s1>
        <s1><string >2aaa-1</string></s1>
    </child1>
    <child1>aaa-2</child1>
    <parent>
        <string >BBB</string>
    </parent>
    <nb>
        <string>1</string>
    </nb>
    <child2>bbb-1</child2>
</data>
```

And XSL file with a name space "ser":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ser="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization" >
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="ser:data">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="ser:parent"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="ser:parent[string = 'AAA']">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::ser:nb[1]"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="string | following-sibling::ser:nb[1] | following-sibling::ser:child1[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="ser:parent[string != 'AAA']">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::ser:nb[1]"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="string | following-sibling::ser:nb[1] | following-sibling::ser:child2[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use the prefix "ser:" it produces :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization">
   <parent>
      <string xmlns="">AAA</string>
      <nb>
               <string>2</string>
         </nb>
      <child1>aaa-1
        <s1><string >1aaa-1</string></s1>
        <s1><string >2aaa-1</string></s1>
      </child1>
      <child1>aaa-2</child1>
   </parent>
        BBB
    </data>
```

While expected is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <parent>
      <string>AAA</string>
      <nb>
               <string>2</string>
         </nb>
      <child1>aaa-1
        <s1><string >1aaa-1 </string></s1>
        <s1><string >2aaa-1</string></s1>
      </child1>
      <child1>aaa-2</child1>
   </parent>
   <parent>
      <string>BBB</string>
         <nb>
               <string>1</string>
         </nb>
      <child2>bbb-1</child2>
</data>
```

The childe2 nodes are not retrived ...
What is wrong ?
It works well when no name space is used.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

> The childe2 nodes are not retrived ... What is wrong ? It works well
>   when no name space is used.

It's probably because your match `ser:parent[string != 'AAA']` never matches anything.

This is because in your second `ser:parent`, the child `string` is in the default namespace `http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization` (whereas `string` is in an empty namespace in the first `ser:parent`).

Consider using an xsl:key instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ser="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="elemByParent" match="ser:data/*[not(self::ser:parent)]" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ser:parent[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ser:data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|ser:parent"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ser:parent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|key('elemByParent',generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ser:s1"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJr

Comment: In this solution, the node s1 of child1 is not retrived. My real input file is complex : with many nested levels for child1 and child2.

Comment: @asx - Huh? `s1` isn't a child of `child1`; it's a child of `data`. I specifically removed `s1` elements because they weren't included in your "_While expected is_" output example. If they should be included, please update your expected output example and let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: I can't explain the difference between the match="ser:parent[string = 'AAA'] and  match="ser:parent[string != 'AAA']. Can you precise  :
"This is because in your second ser:parent, the child string is in the default namespace" ?

Comment: Sorry : I just modified the expected output. I've to copy the number "nb" of following full nodes child1 and child2 inside the parents node. If AAA then child1 else child2.
Would it be possible to define th default path for avoid the prefix ?

Comment: In the expected output the `s1` elements still aren't children of child1/child2; is this on purpose? What happens if you just remove the template stripping s1? (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJr/1) If you want to avoid the prefix, you could try changing `ser:parent[string != 'AAA']` to `ser:parent[. != 'AAA']`.

Comment: 1/ Expected ouput  is corrected 2/I tested with the real input : it seems to be OK when the template s1 is removed. 3/ could you explain me,  it was 'stripping' action with the initial "<xsl:template match="ser:s1"/>" ?.

Comment: @asx - Because it was an empty template. When it matched `ser:s1` nothing was added to the result tree. Maybe take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#rules to understand how template rules work.

Comment: @asx - Did my answer solve your issue or are you still having problems?

Comment: Yes Daniel, it works very well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `xsl:copy` instruction produces an element with the same name as the original: that is, the same local name, and the same namespace. So if you have `{http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization}data` in the input, and you want `{}data` in the output (changing the namespace, and therefore the name), then you can't use `xsl:copy`; you need to use `xsl:element`.

Comment: The `{a}b` notation Michael is using in this answer means "an element named `b` in the namespace whose URI is `a`.

Comment: The solution proposed by Daniel works very well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am puzzled that Daniel's solution should work, since it makes no attempt to change the namespace of the elements, which your example output suggests is required.